# How to post a List<T> to a WCF Rest service

Tags: wcf, rest, post, service

I have a class

```
[DataContract]
public class Test
{
[DataMemeber]
public string A {get;set;}
[DataMemeber]
public string B {get;set;}
[DataMemeber]
public string C {get;set;}
}
```

I have a Restful WCF method

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "checkupdates",
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]

List<Test> CheckForUpdates(List<Test> testing);
```

How can I post the List object to the service? This is from a wpf client.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

List is equivalent to an array, so the value should be represented as a JSON array. And since the body style says that the request needs to be wrapped, then you should wrap the JSON array in an object with a field named as the parameter:

```
{"testing":[
    {"A":"Value of A1","B":"Value of B1","C":"Value of C1"},
    {"A":"Value of A2","B":"Value of B2","C":"Value of C2"},
    {"A":"Value of A3","B":"Value of B3","C":"Value of C3"}]}
```

If the request were not wrapped (BodyStyle of Bare or WrappedResponse) then you wouldn't need the wrapping object, and this would be a request for the operation:

```
[
  {"A":"Value of A1","B":"Value of B1","C":"Value of C1"},
  {"A":"Value of A2","B":"Value of B2","C":"Value of C2"},
  {"A":"Value of A3","B":"Value of B3","C":"Value of C3"}
]
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to give me an example. WIll change the BodyStyle make life any easier?

Comment: If the BodyStyle is Bare (or WrappedResponse, meaning the request isn't wrapped), then you don't need the wrapping object - I'll update the answer with the request for the Bare case.